# Does the German language have some words used almost exclusively by/for young children?

Tags: baby-talk

In English, when speaking to children, adults sometimes use words like "doggie" for dog, "boo-boo" to refer to an injury, or "upsy-daisy" if a child falls. Do Germans have something similar when they speak to babies and young children?

Comment: Do you think there is any language that doesn't have such words?

Comment: @Robert The question literally asks whether there are such words in German, to which the answer is clearly yes. However, looking just beyond the literal meaning of the words in the question, OP obviously wants to know about some specific examples in German.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee It wouldn't hurt to specifically ask for examples in the question, though.

Comment: Intersting, "Bonbon" used to be a children's language and was included into the normal vocabulary https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kindersprache

Comment: Hm. I know quite a lot of adult writing that uses the word “doggie”.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, German does have these kind of words. I'll borrow some of your examples:

- *Doggie* would be *Wauwau*, also a pretty childish term.
- *Boo-boo* could be translated as *Wehweh*, *Wehchen* or plainly as *Aua* (which is in **this** context rather used for children/babies).
- *Upsy-daisy* is similar to *Hoppla*, but that's a term that can be used for other age groups, too.

Other examples would be *pipi* and *kaka*, translated as *pee-pee* and *poo-poo*. (credits to [@Fabby](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/13737/fabby))

You will notice the similarities here: doubling the syllables. 
This is often an indicator for more childish words, or words used with babies. This can be derived from the simplicity of these words, regarding the low state of language development of the babies. (e.g.  *Wehweh*, *Mama*, *Papa*,...)

The words are often results of onomatopoeia, too: e.g. *Wauwau*, *Lala* (music), *BrummBrumm* (car), ...

Comment: You forgot "kaka" which is a universal Indo-European word... (at least in the ones I know...)  **;-)**

Comment: *Die Lulu* in some dialects is the same as *das Pipi*. Which is of course very awkward if your name is literally *Lulu*. (*lullen* – to pee)

Comment: *Das Baba* is anything the baby should not touch.

Comment: teita mitm wauzi ...

Comment: So, und nach dem Mammam (essen) machen wir Heiaheia (wir gehen schlafen). Ba, das ist igittegitt (eklig).

Comment: @userunknown, ich kenn essen als "njam njam".

Comment: Essen can be *Happa* or *Happa-Happa*. Dirty things are *bäh* or *bäh-bäh* or *i-bäh*. *Hoppe-hoppe* (probably from *hüpfen)* for bouncing, e.g. on a lap (there is the [Hoppe hoppe Reiter song](https://www.mamalisa.com/?t=es&p=392)). There's the [Da da da song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LnBSc28Obs4) from the 1980s.

Comment: Pullermann - Word for the male parts

Comment: how the world is small - *pipi* and *caca* are also used in French.They may be, in specific circumstances, used by adults between adults.

Comment: @Ulf *Mumu* for the vulva.

Comment: I like how a *wauwau* edited this answer.

Comment: Not sure why there's a question mark on "pee-pee," but if there's any question, yes, that's an English euphemism for urine or urinating.

Comment: @WoJ It's more than French alone: see [first comment](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/47208/does-the-german-language-have-some-words-used-almost-exclusively-by-for-young-ch/47210#comment114415_47210): It's in all the Indo-Europen languages I can speak from Afrikaans to по-русски...

Comment: @Fabby: It's not even restricted to IE languages. *All* natural spoken human languages have some kind of a "baby talk" lexicon, and the words in it tend to follow a similar pattern of reduplicated simple CV syllables derived from the first recognizably speech-like "babbling" sounds made by infants learning to talk. ["Mama" and "papa"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mama_and_papa) are common examples of such words, and occur in a worldwide distribution that cuts in a distinctive way across language family boundaries.

Comment: I was specifically talking about [kaka](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/47208/does-the-german-language-have-some-words-used-almost-exclusively-by-for-young-ch/47210?noredirect=1#comment114415_47210) @IlmariKaronen (Also: I'm not a linguist)  **;-)**

Answer (score 23):

> Do Germans have something similar when they speak to babies and young children?

Yes, we do. This is called *Baby Talk*. On the German [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_Talk) it is defined as follows:

> Unter **Baby Talk** oder **Motherese** (Aussprache: [ˈmʌðəɹiːs]; engl.), fachsprachlich *Infant-directed speech*, ungenau auch *Ammensprache*, *Kinder-* oder *Babysprache* oder umgangssprachlich *„Mutterisch“* oder *„Elterisch“* genannt, versteht man eine Varietät einer Sprache, die bevorzugt gegenüber Säuglingen und Kleinkindern gebraucht wird.

An example is *Husch-Husch* for *Eisenbahn* (a train).

Comment: Ich habe die Kommentare über die ursprüngliche Fassung der Antwort gelöscht. Falls jemand denkt, dass es es unserer Etikette entspricht, Fragen derart wortwörtlich zu nehmen, möge er dies bitte auf [meta] vorbringen.

Comment: Ergänzenswert zu diesem "bevorzugt" wäre an dieser Stelle der Hinweis auf die Sprache 'Kindisch'. Oder die Infantilisierung des Sprachgebrauchs, wenn exakt diese oder ähnliche Wörter und Wendungen unter Erwachsenen verwendet werden. Das is nämlich wirklich zum Bäuerchen mit Land machen.

Answer (score 10):

Also commonly used:

> - in die **Heia** gehen = ins **Bett** gehen *(go to bed)*
> - killekille machen = kitzeln *(to tickle)*
> - kikeriki = den Ruf des Hahns nachahmen *(mimic the cock's call)*
> - Töfftöff = Auto *(car)*
> - winke, winke machen = mit der Hand winken *(wave one's hand)*

All examples are labelled as *Kindersprache* by [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/kikeriki), unfortunately you can't specify that in the search.

Comment: Oje, das Wort "killekille" weckt schreckliche Erinnerungen :-O

Comment: @Iris: Dann wurdest du wohl – befummelt?

Comment: ich fange bis heute an hysterisch zu kichern, wenn man auf mich zukommt, die Hände ausstreckt, die Finger bewegt und "Killekille" sagt. Harte Konditionierung :´D

Answer (score 2):

some words that come to my mind (and no idea how common they are :D )

- `papa` - daddy / father
- `mama` - mom / mother
- `opi` - grandfather
- `omi` - grandmother
- `pipi` and `kacka`  - things better to be brought to the toilet
- `Bubu` (machen)     - sleep ( to sleep )
- `Balla` - a ball
- `Happi` - pacifier
- `Nucki` - pacifier
- `Schnulli`- pacifier
- `kiekuck!` - after hiding for some seconds, to greet the baby when it sees you
- `Pulla` - baby bottle